# How to add string to IEnumerable - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following class:

```
class A
{
  public IEnumerable Song { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Index i have code like this:

```
public ActionResult 
{
    a.Song = (Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs"),
                           file)).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

This code is not working how can i add string path to IEnumerable Song? Or is there a better way or other way to do this rather than using IEnumerable?

-- I dont understand -ve ratings? It is a legit question? 
As i described above i am trying to collect 4 or 5 url's as string under a.Song. 
The above code returs character like 134 char string array. Which is not what i am trying to get. I hope this explaination helps but i still dont understand -ve ratings. Can people who assing -ve rating explain why they did that?

Comment: What does "code is not working" mean? Is it throwing an exception? Is it compiling? Is it producing no/incorrect output? You need to be more specific.

Comment: The signature of `ActionResult` is mysterious. Everything is, actually.

Comment: @YoryeNathan ...and presence of a return value.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That is what caught my eye in the first place. Then I also noticed it has no return value nor brackets.

Comment: IEnumerable is intended for iteration through a collection. It doesn't support modification of the collection. You will need to expose ICollection or IList etc to allow modification.

Comment: Probably OP just needs a.Song = new List<string>{Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs"),
                           file)};

Comment: @nonnb. False. He is assigning a `List<T>` reference to an `IEnumerable` variable. Totally legit.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I never knew that `Path` implements `IEnumerable`. It's obvious that he wants to add a single element to the already existing IEnumerable. He doesn't want the IEnumerable to be the single element, broken into pieces in some undefined manner.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Path.Combine returns string which is IEnumarable on characters

Comment: @YoryeNathan I only looked at the `ToList<T>` part. My bad. But actually, `Path.Combine` returns `string`, which is `IEnumerable<char>`. So I was half-right :-P

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes you were :)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Title of the OP's post is "How to Add String to IEnumerable"

Comment: @AmitMittal - I think your response is right.

Comment: @YoryeNathan - Yes you are correct i am getting list of <char> which is what was throwing me off. And i wanted list of strings which in this case is "url's"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEnumerable is a sequence Generator from a StateMachine.  You cannot add an item by this way for an IEnumerable. But as most of the collections are derived from it, you can assign a collection to it.

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/songs"),
                           file));
a.Song = list;
```

This will work.

Here a List is created and the path is added to it.

Comment: Actually, IEnumerable is a sequence that can give you a state machine that you can use to enumerate the sequence.

Comment: You are right. Its a typo. I have edited the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to have:

```
class A
{
     List<string> songs=new List<string>();
     public IEnumerable<string> Songs { get{ return songs;}}
     public void Add(string song)
     {
         songs.Add(song);
     }
}
```

Then you use:

```
var a = new A();

a.Add(...);
```

this allow you to expose a read only collection, with an explicit way to add songs.